# Como mudar o placehoder de acordo com o value do select?

Tags: jquery

Montei esse código e quando o usuário escolher `cafe` no campo `<input type='search'>` deve aparecer por exemplo: `Cimo, 3Corações, Utam`.

Se o usuário escolher `refrigerante` ele deverá mostrar no campo: `Coca, Pespi, Tubaina`.

Mas esses valores devem ser mostrados no placeholder.

Código:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="col-sm-9"> 
            <div class="col-sm-3 nav-container">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <!--  <select id="evento" name="evento" onchange="campoSelect(this.value)" required> ...  -->
                  <select class="form-control " id="tipo" name="tipo" onchange="campoSelect(this.value)"  required>
                     <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione TIpo</option>
                     <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
                     <option value="detergente">Detergente</option>
                     <option value="refiegerante">Refrigenrante</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"> 
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" name="pesquisar" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<script>

If (val = cafe){
   mensagem = "Cimo, 3Corações,Utam";
}
If (val = refrigerante ){
   mensagem = "Coca, Pespi,Cutuba";
}
function campoSelect(val){
   document.getElementById("mensagem").placeholder = val;
}  

</script>
```

Comment: Tente alterar seu if de (val = cafe), para if(value === "cafe") e também coloque no gelElementById o ID referente ao select que pelo que eu vi é id="tipo" então ficaria getElementById("tipo")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um objeto para fazer o mapeamento de chave/valor com base no `value` das opções existentes:

```
var placeholders = {
  'cafe': 'Cimo, 3Corações, Utam',
  'refrigerante': 'Coca, Pepsi, Catuaba'
};
```

No caso do item não existir em `placeholders`, você pode fazer um fallback para exibir um valor padrão. Considerando o exemplo acima, `placeholders['foo']` me retornaria `undefined`, então pode-se contornar isso com:

```
var placeholder = placeholders['foo'] || 'Search term...';
console.log(placeholder); // Search term...
```

Por fim basta trocar o atributo do `input` utilizando a função [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```js
$(function(){
  
  var placeholders = {
    'cafe': 'Cimo, 3Corações, Utam',
    'refrigerante': 'Coca, Pepsi, Catuaba'
  };

  $('#tipo').on('change', function(){      
    var placeholder = placeholders[$(this).val()] || 'Search term...';
    $('input').attr('placeholder', placeholder);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control " id="tipo" name="tipo" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione o Tipo</option>
  <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
  <option value="detergente">Detergente</option>
  <option value="refrigerante">Refrigerante</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
```

Comment: VAleu era isso mesmo ficou show   valeu a  ajuda nota 10